# What's green text in VS Code (e.g. FILE) ? I am programming in C and i was wondering what green text in VS Code symbolizes

Tags: c, file, visual-studio-code

I am programming in C and sometimes i have seen green text in VS Code while doing C programming. For example "FILE" is green. What does green text symbolize/resemble in VS Code in C programming?

Comment: Did you try hovering your mouse over it to get a tooltip?

Comment: Well, `FILE` is a type name. So I guess it symbolizes type names (unless it is commented out..).

Comment: depends on the Theme you select what color it has, use the TextMate scope inspector